# Iterating over numpy elements with interruptions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently facing the following problem:
I have two arrays:

```
a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
b=np.array([False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
```

I start iterating over array `a` from an arbitrary starting point, adding the elements from the beginning of the array.
So doing this for the first two steps (as indicated by the indices), starting from index 2:

```
step_1=np.array([1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
step_2=np.array([1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
```

[Important: I don't create a new array every time. this is just to visualize the steps]

At the same time I start iterating over array `b`. Whenever `b`shows `True`, I skip the step of adding the numbers and simply continue with the next iteration step, but without advancing the position of the number that I want to add.

```
import numpy as np
offset=2
position=0
for index in range(offset,len(a)):
    if b[index]:
        continue
    a[index]=a[index]+a[position]
    position +=1
>>>a=array([ 1,  2,  4,  4,  7, 10, 11, 15, 19, 21, 26])
```

You can see in the result that the fourth element stayed `4` and the `2` that would normally have been added went to the `5` (resulting in the `7`).

Is there any way to simplify my code?
I have to run it very often and wonder if there is a way that could make my live easier instead of having to go through the if-statement every time while also adding +1 to the position variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(np.logical_not(b))[offset:]
for s,t in enumerate(indices):
    a[t] += a[s+position]
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the help. A very nice solution.